# How do I upload files to localhost in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, localhost

I'm trying to test a WordPress installation in XAMPP for OS X (running version 0.7.3 because I prefer the included version of phpMyAdmin).  When I try to upload media files, it returns an error about not having a temporary folder.  Same with any upload form I test in other applications.

Is there anything I can do to get it to allow uploads to function normally, as if it were a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply need to create a /tmp and /wwwtmp in your sites root directory.
Check the permissions set for these directories